# Amazon ElastiCache operations consistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I cannot find any documentation for Amazon ElastiCache operations consistency. I'm interested particularly in Get, Set, Delete operations. What I have found though, is description of the `delete` method in library which I am using:  https://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/

```
/// This method corresponds to the "delete" command in the memcache protocol.
/// It will immediately delete the given key and corresponding value.
/// Use the overloads to specify an amount of time the item should be in the delete queue on the server,
/// or to specify a custom hash to override server selection.
```

Could someone provide me information what are the consistencies of the operations? (E.g how fast "delete" operation will be executed? If I'll try to get deleted item just afterwards, will it be deleted? Is it eventual consistency or not?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

tl;dr; Memcached's operations are all atomic

More here:

- [Cache consistency when using memcached and a rdbms like MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802772/cache-consistency-when-using-memcached-and-a-rdbms-like-mysql)
- [How are concurrent updates handled in Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134883/how-are-concurrent-updates-handled-in-memcached/16138322#16138322)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. An operation can be atomic with different levels of consistency.